# log4jdbc does not work with spring boot 2.7.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4jdbc

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.0, and I used the Log4JDBC dependency to log queries with its parameters.

I added the dependency to build.gradle
implementation 'ru.vasiand:spring-boot-starter-log4jdbc:1.1.0'

I added the configuration in application.yaml
log4jdbc:
auto:
load:
popular:
drivers: false
dump:
sql:
maxlinelength: 0
addsemicolon: false
trim:
sql:
extrablanklines: false

I cannot see any logs for Log4JDBC what I see is hibernate logs
select name from users u where u.username=?

what I except is find ready to run query like
select name from users u where u.username='username'

I tried to change the version of the dependency to 2.0.0, but it did not work.

Comment: Hi, did you use https://github.com/candrews/log4jdbc-spring-boot-starter before? That library was compatible with your version. Your currenty library requires Spring Boot 3+. Have you checked that?

Comment: No, because the project is already in production, I will be unable to change the Spring Boot version. I'm trying to use it in the current version.